# AttributeError: __enter__ -stackoverflow

Tags: python

I'm writing a python program and run in Google Colaboratory. But it failed to pass the compiling and gave the AttributeError. Any body can help me? Thanks a lot.

```
 total = []
 with tf.compat.v1.Session as sess:
      sess.run(init_op)
      writer = tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter('graphs',sess.graph)
```

AttributeError: **enter**

Comment: Always include the entirety of your program and the whole error message.

Answer (score 0):

Add brackets to `Session`.

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
```